# OpenMP with a Function for Generating Random Numbers

Tags: function, loops, dependencies, openmp

I am going to use OpenMP to parallel my code which is for particles' motion through a fluid. In order to be able to model the Brownian motion of the particles I use a free random generator library. I have an object of the random generator class:

```
Class_rand Obj_rand;
```

I can call the following member function to get a random value:

```
Obj_rand.Func_rand();
```

The structure that part of my code which is supposed to be parallelized is as follows:

```
Class_rand Obj_rand;
...
for (all of the time steps){
  //some tasks are done just by the master root

  #pragma omp parallel
  {
    //declaration all of the required private variables

    for (all of the particles : each thread is tasked with solving a set of particles' equations)
    {
       //some tasks are done

       this_rand_value = Obj_rand.Func_rand();

       //some tasks are done: particles position and velocity are updated
    }
  }
}
```

For this structure, I get segmentation faults, and this is because the object Obj_rand is shared between all of the threads, so it obviously shouldn't work. Hence, I slightly adjusted the structure of my code:

```
for (all of the time steps){
  //some tasks are done just by the master root

  #pragma omp parallel
  {
    //declaration all of the required private variables

    Class_rand Obj_rand;

    for (all of the particles : each thread is tasked with solving a set of particles' equations)
    {
       //some tasks are done

       this_rand_value = Obj_rand.Func_rand();

       //some tasks are done: particles position and velocity are updated
    }
  }
}
```

As you see, I declare my random generator in the parallel region so that its memory is allocated on the stack. This structure works very well in a parallel fashion, but in the meantime there is a huge conceptual problem:

Since the random generator objects are declared at each time step, they generate the same sequence of random numbers at each time step, and consequently the Brownian motion of the particles is not modeled correctly.

Do you think I have to return to the first structure, and try to modify the library I have downloaded for generating random numbers in such a manner that it does not have anything shared between threads? I hope this is not the case because I don't like to go through that code!

I would be grateful if anyone could please help me.

Best

Comment: Use one global PRNG to seed the thread-local PRNGs at each step. Put the call to `global.Func_rand()` in an OpenMP `critical` construct in order to prevent it from crashing. Make sure that you use a high-quality PRNG, e.g. MT19937, in order to prevent correlations.

Comment: Thank you very much... It was a brilliant idea and it worked very well, but I decided to declare a pointer of the RNG objects, so that each thread had its own object. In this manner they don't interfere with each other and I don't have to use "critical", so it's a little bit faster! Thanks a lot again.

Comment: If you are at all concerned about the validity of your results you need to ensure that the random number generators in each thread are generating disjoint streams, otherwise you are simply sampling the same space more than once, and therefore biasing your results. (Choosing a random or thread dependent seed to initialize a random number generator does not guarantee that). For inspiration, look at something like www.thesalmons.org/john/random123/papers/random123sc11.pdf

Comment: Thanks Jim. What I have done is to assign several different sequences of random numbers to the threads; I generated several pairs of seeds (since my RNG gets two seeds to be initialized) for different threads, and I examined the first ten random numbers for each thread... They are different from one thread to another... Do you think something might still be problematic?

Comment: Yes, of course it could still be wrong. You need to prove that you're getting disjoint sequences, not just look at some sub-sequence. (One of the streams could have a ten long prefix, and then be the same as the other one!). This isn't about experiment, but proof. You need a random number generator that has a large enough state space, and a "boost" function so that you can guarantee that you're sampling different parts of the state space in each thread.

Comment: I got your point. Actually, I use a random number generator originally appeared in "Toward a Universal Random Number Generator" by George Marsaglia and Arif Zaman. Florida State University Report: FSU-SCRI-87-50 (1987) It was later modified by F. James and published in "A Review of Pseudo-random Number Generators" It has been claimed to have a period of 2^144, which is outstanding!